# Unable to access Magento Due To ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: magento2, apache2

Magento was working fine but then on trying to access http://80.85.85.79/berguard_stationery
I get an error:
`This page isn’t working
80.85.85.79 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

**I have *three* magento installations on the same server and visiting the urls for all of them brings up the same error**.

From the research I have done, I came across [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/apache2-on-ubuntu-18-10-all-sites-respond-with-err_empty_response-ping-works) but it wasn't helpful on how to solve the error.

This error is not logged in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Below is my virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@shop.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName shop.com
    ServerAlias shop.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have edited my virtualhost file to:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento2/magento2-2.3>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@shop.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName shop.com
    ServerAlias shop.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/magento2-2.3>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
</VirtualHost>
```

I have edited my virtualhost file to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        #ServerName shop.com
        #ServerAlias shop.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/magento2-2.3/pub

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I still have the error showing up.

**How do I go about solving this error?**
[image: Screenshot of error displayed in browser]

Comment: Without having a lot of information my money is on this request not even hitting Magento. I'd probably check your apache setup if it actually ends up in the right directory for example

Comment: @SanderMangel I have edited the post to include the virtual host file I am using. Take a look at my `DocumentRoot`

Comment: If it's Magento 2 it should probably point to the `pub` directory. I'm also missing some other stuff like `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride All`

Comment: @SanderMangel I have edited my question, please take a look. Magento was actually working fine 3 days ago. `DocumentRoot` was pointing to `html`. For configuring magento2 on linode, I was following [https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/ecommerce/install-magento-on-ubuntu-16-04/#configure-apache]

Comment: Afaik the `DocumentRoot` should point to `pub` where the `index.php` is. Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html for more details

Comment: @SanderMangel I have checked https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html and changed `DocumentRoot` to point to `pub` but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, for some reason Port 80 on the server was closed.
So I reopened Port 80 using;

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then importantly for the changes to persist even when server is restarted ;

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```